# Verification Company Signed Certificate for Localhost

Tags: ssl, openssl

Is it possible to have verisign, comodo, etc signed certificate instead of having self signed certificate on localhost?

Comment: As per [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793174/third-party-signed-ssl-certificate-for-localhost-127-0-0-1), it is possible.

Comment: This may seem unwise coming from a wise man like me, but I'm going to ask anyway, what is SO?

Comment: Thanks for the link, young man.