# Get valid ssl certificate for desktop app?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I make some software, which send request and server send response on https:/127.0.0.1:1234 on browser. I try create self signed sertificate, but its not allowed on firefox. How to get valid trusted cert?

Comment: You can add cert(s) to Firefox (but manually), otherwise see (automatically searched for you in 'related') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793174/third-party-signed-ssl-certificate-for-localhost-or-127-0-0-1?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you can't get a valid trusted cert on localhost because this certificate + key would then be valid on every computer.
In the end anybody owning your software could extract this certificate + key from your program and use it to attack other software.

Therefore you have to generate a new key pair and certificate on each system after installation and then import the certificate to the Firefox root ca list.

Answer (score -1):

There are more than one way to get SSL for website, But for desktop you need to active system security system to save your data form penetrations.