# How to fix "Unable to connect to https://127.0.0.1 SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate"

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, curl, php-curl

I know there are several posts about this topic but I've tried a lot and nothing has worked.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://127.0.0.1:2288");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ":" . $this->password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pRequest);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

When I execute it on Ubuntu 20.04 machine, i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to connect to https://127.0.0.1:2288/ Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

The certificate is the current version from curl.se/docs/caextract.html

php.ini:

```
extension=curl
extension=php_curl.dll
curl.cainfo="/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"
```

What else can I do without prohibiting curl ssl connections?

Comment: Remove the s from https?

Comment: @theking2 I think the whole point is to keep the s!

Comment: @NigelRen I cannot see a use case to access local files over an encrypted channel.

Comment: Why not encrypt everything? Having the same conditions in a development system as on the production system is a use case

Comment: @theking2, testing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl error 60, SSL certificate issue: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha)

Comment: Some of the answers posted here might also be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802552/2657515

Answer (score 0):

If you are using self-signed certificates you either have to add it to your trusted certificates or you have to turn validation off.
For the second case just switch the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting *securely* to localhost on Ubuntu and, as your error indicates, your server is responding with a *self-signed* certificate. Your code specifies that curl should attempt to verify the host it's connecting to (localhost, in your case):

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), that value of `2` in your code for `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` is documented thusly:

> 2 to verify that a Common Name field or a Subject Alternate Name field in the SSL peer certificate matches the provided hostname. 0 to not check the names. 1 should not be used. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).

If you want to strictly follow the documentation's recommendation, you'd have to map some domain onto localhost and install a cert for that domain on your server. AFAIK, you [cannot get a cert for 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793174/third-party-signed-ssl-certificate-for-localhost-or-127-0-0-1) because that special IP address always refers to localhost...sort of a long story but it makes no sense for anyone to sign such a cert.

Your other option is to tell curl not to verify the ssl connection `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to zero:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// you may also need to set this?
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

That tells curl not to bother validating the certificate. This *should* be fairly safe if your are in control of your own server and if your server hasn't been compromised somehow.

**EDIT**
I would add that downloading the cert extract from curl.se just grabs a bundle of widely trusted signatures/certificates that happens to be the bundle used by [Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/Included_Certificates). This cert bundle is used to check any *domain* that you might visit by comparing the signature on that domain's certificate to some big/important certificates that have been signed by supposedly trustworthy organizations. It will never be helpful in validating a self-signed certificate. For more information about this elaborate concept, try reading about [Web of Trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust).

I should also mention that you might be able to use a few commands to grab the certificate that your local machine coughs up and configure your curl code to use that certificate, HOWEVER, the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` setting of `2` instructs curl to check the `Common Name` field of this certificate against the IP address or domain to which you are connecting. On my ubuntu workstation, the certificate's Common Name is 'Ubuntu' -- and that won't match either localhost or 127.0.0.1. For this approach to work, you'll either have to generate a new cert for your machine with a Common Name that matches the address to which you connect (localhost or 127.0.0.1) OR you'll need to set up something to name your machine 'ubuntu' on your local network.

Comment: If I set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to zero, same error occurs

Comment: Hmmm...it was working on my machine. I edited my post so that the code also sets CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Please... do not set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585500/2657515

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt that other post is never going to fix a situation where someone is using a **self-signed* certificate. No matter which bundle of CA root certificates you use, no matter how up to date, it will not verify a self-signed cert.